# Console output of container app is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an Action Extension which launches my container app. Everything works fine except that Xcode console output is still empty after

```
print("TEST")
```

Screenshots :

Before print call :
[image]

After :

[image]

Comment: What happens if you just let the method run to completion? I believe logging is asynchronous by default.

Comment: No changes. My console shows output from the action extension thread, not the one from container app. Console output is positioned on 'All Output', not 'Debugger' or 'Target output'. In debug mode, just after the container app launched, I attach the container app to the debug process to be sure.

Comment: Have you tried `NSLog`?

Comment: Yes, no output either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode log console shows prints from the running app in Xcode. 
In my case, I was interested in the log output of the container app, not the extension app.

The solution is :

1. Run the container app from xcode first
2. Then, launch your app
   extension from your home screen

When calling the container app from the app extension, you'll see your container app prints on Xcode log console